# Send email from php at specified time

Tags: email, sms, phpmailer, php

I'm trying to set up a "reminder" system in my phone through php.  I have a form set up for me to input an email(which is actually my phone number address so it is sent as a SMS) and send a message to myself.  I'm using the basic code:

```
 mail( $to, '$subject', $message );
```

Right now my emails are sent immediately when the php is run.  Is there a way to specify a date and time for the email to be sent?

Comment: which platform you are using. If you are using linux then cron job will do for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By CRON jobs, We can set an interval by which a specific PHP script is executed repeatedly.

The logic here is: PHP script checks if the specified date/time to send the email is already passed or not. If passed, send the email.

If we set the CRON job interval to 1 hour, in the worst case, the email can be sent with the delay of 1 hour and the best case can be as low as 1 second..

By the way you will have to add the date field to your form to specify the date or time at which you will have to send the email

Comment: I have a date field in my HTML form which then translates to a UNIX timestamp in php so I can add and subtract from that time in order to receive an email/SMS 30 minutes before my event is supposed to take place.  Will this affect the CRON job because my php is based entirely off $_GETting an HTML form?

Comment: In this case, you will have to create a DB entry for each form submision.. Our PHP script, which will be executed at specific intervals, will look into each DB entry for expired dates and send mail. is it clear?

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, the answer could not be made any longer than this.

Yes there is a way: `CRON` jobs

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=PHP%20run%20cron&oq=PHP%20run%20cron&gs_l=hp.3..0l2j0i22i30j0i22i10i30j0i22i30l6.289.2974.0.3178.14.13.1.0.0.0.243.1464.7j2j3.12.0...0.0...1c.1.9.hp.HT2pjIw3Zr8)

For Windows, you could

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=cron%20job%20windows&oq=cron%20job%20windows&gs_l=hp.3..0l4j0i22i30l6.145.3275.0.3456.16.14.0.2.2.1.298.1779.7j2j4.13.0...0.0...1c.1.9.hp.9JqofiS-Y6w)

Comment: Yep, Click that Google link :)

Comment: yes corn jobs which will let you execute a server-side page (php) in a specific time.in that file you can do all that.(with connecting to database or using any logic for that).

Comment: Ooops, Thanks! fixed. Thanks Ann :)

Answer (score 1):

please use CRON Job it will help you

CRON job is provided by Hosting